# Removing parenthesis from phone numbers and adding dash using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm brand new to PHP, so, forgive me if this is an easy question, but I can't really figure out how to use `preg_replace` to strip the parenthesis from the area codes in my phone numbers and add a dash between the area code and the first 3 digits.

Right now all of my phone numbers are stored separately in each person array (which are in the index file) in this format: `(800) 111-1111`.

I want to get them to print out like this: `800-111-1111` and I want to make this all happen in the `setphoneNumber` function of my `Person` class.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
$this-> phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;  
$pattern = ('/\D+/');
$replacement = '';
if(is_string($phoneNumber)) {
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $this -> phoneNumber);
} else {
    user_error("Error: Person's phone number must be a string");
}
```

Any modifications that I do to it either gives me an unmatched parenthesis at offset error or a no ending delimiter error (which occurs when I set `$pattern` as `(')'`);

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

If the initial format is always the same, I wouldn't bother defining a variable for the replacement or the pattern

Try this:

```php
preg_replace(array("(",") "),"", $this->phoneNumber);
```

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting No ending matching delimiter ')' error after replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, Brian?

```
$pattern = array('/\(/', '/\) /');
$replacement = array('', '-');
if(is_string($phoneNumber)) {
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $this -> phoneNumber);
}
```

It doesn't account for people using a period in replace of a hyphen though (like 800.111.1111)... but it wouldn't take a whole lot more to make it function for that as well.  You'd just want to trim out all the excess then make sure you're replacing the first period (between area code and the next block of numbers) with a space instead of a hyphen, like you'd do to the remaining periods.

**UPDATE:**

I haven't tested this extensively, but this should work for what you're after, as well as accommodate people that use a decimal phone number format (ie 800.111.1111).

```
$pattern = array('/ /','/[(](.*)[)](.*)(-)(.*)/','/(.*)(\.)(.*)(\.)(.*)/');
$replacement = array('','$1-$2-$4','$1-$3-$5');
if(is_string($phoneNumber)) {
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $this -> phoneNumber);
}
```